# Google Analytics - split data by platform

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-filters

I have an application that is available on multiple platforms:

- web
- desktop/native (Windows / macOS)
- phone/tablet (Android / iOS)

The front-end of all platforms is shared. It's built with React.
Right now, all analytics data is sent to the same account/property/view.

I want to have precise data about the usage and user technology (operative systems, versions, etc) of my desktop apps. Because, if I see the operative systems or global usage, I don't know which data is from the web application and which data is from the desktop/native app.

I would like to do the same for the mobile apps, because I want to have views with only data from the native apps, and not from users accessing my web app on mobile devices.

But, I would also want to have an overall view, so that I can see the global usage without having to sum the values from different views.

What is the best way to split the data and achieve what I want/need?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not available in Google Analytics you would have to use Google Analytics Reporting API to merge the data.

If you are using Google Analytics 360 (Premium), you have the option to use Roll Up property. *Even then you won't be able to use Firebase Analytics in Roll Up properties*.

> Roll-Up Reporting aggregates data from multiple Analytics properties and lets you see that data together in the same reports.
>
> Roll-Up Reporting comprises two types of properties:
>
> Source Properties: Individual Analytics properties that include data from a single site, app, or internet-connected device.
>
> Roll-Up Properties: Properties that serve as aggregators of the data from multiple Source Properties.

[Official guide to Roll Up Properties](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6033415)